# PHP rounding problem (5.2.3)?

Tags: php, rounding

I'm wondering if I found an issue with the rounding in PHP, specifically 5.2.3 (I'm not sure about other versions at the moment):

```
$t = 0;

$taxAmount = (5.000 / 100) * 0.7;
$t += $taxAmount;

var_dump($t); // float(0.035)
var_dump(round($t, 2)); // float(0.03)
var_dump(number_format($t, 2)); // string(4) "0.03"
```

To me 0.035 should round to 0.04 or am I just crazy?

**Edit**

Thxs to [NebyGemini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187197/php-rounding-problem-5-2-3/2187251#2187251), I figured I would do this instead:

```
$t = 0;

$taxAmount = bcmul(bcdiv(5.000, 100, 3), 0.7, 3);
$t += $taxAmount;

var_dump($t); // float(0.035)
var_dump(round($t, 2)); // float(0.04)
var_dump(number_format($t, 2)); // string(4) "0.04"
```

Which works perfect.

BTW, I'm calculating a tax in a shopping cart. The order total is the 0.70 (70 cents) and the tax is 5%.

**Edit**

Thxs to [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187197/php-rounding-problem-5-2-3/2187208#2187208), this is to show where the problem lies:

```
printf('%.18F', 5.000 / 100 * 0.7);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Floats are evil.**

Quoting the [PHP manual documentation on *Floating Point numbers*](http://php.net/float):

> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and never compare floating point numbers for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the [arbitrary precision math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) functions are available.

If you want to know why and how floats work I recommend watching:
 [Everything you didn't want to know about JavaScript numbers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqHDDtVYJRI)

Comment: Thanks, ended up using the bc math functions.

Answer (score 3):

Python says:

```
>>> repr(5./100*0.7)
'0.034999999999999996'
```

This is due to IEEE754 accuracy limitations. Use a fixed-point type if you need exact accuracy.

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to get this in PHP?

Comment: `printf('%.18F', 5.000 / 100 * 0.7);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, but there's a issue that number self transform to "99999..."