# mysql returns not exact value in max function when dealing with floats?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, max

Look at this query please

```
SELECT max( val_amd ) FROM `best_deposits`
```

I have the max value in the table equal to 14.6(the fields has type `float`),

But it returns `14.3599996566772`

why does it happen, and how can i get the exact value?

Thanks much

Comment: I hope you meant that you stored 14.36 in the field...

Comment: please see my edit and the providet links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**floats are evil!**

*NEVER* use floats for storing amounts or prices. instead of that, use an int and store the amount in cents. thats the *only* way to get around those problems forever.

why this happens: because [floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) **can't** be saved exactly in many cases (such as 0.6 in your case)

PS: we had those questions a hundret times for different languages till now:

- [Use Float or Decimal for Accounting Application Dollar Amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61872/288773)
- [PHP rounding problem (5.2.3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187197/288773)
- [Rounding problem with double type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4008395/288773)
- [Javascript rounding v c# rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3491079/288773)
- [Python rounding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2880547/288773)
- [... and a lot more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=evil+float+round)

**EDIT:** to your comment: as i said:

> use an int and store the amount in
>   cents

*(alternatively you* could *use an DECIMAL(10,2) (or how big/how much decimal places you need)... not sure about how this works)*

Comment: so, how can i store the float value in table? what type i must use? (it's boring to have two fields for each value:/)

Answer (score 1):

Or you better use "decimal" with length 10,2 or something like that for storing prices.

Comment: double is still a floating point value. Doing a display length of 10,2 won't change the rounding issues with floats. At most it'll just hide them and lead to greater confusion while debugging.

Comment: My mistake. I meant decimal(10,2) as @oezi wrote.